# Excel Macro to Filter Column to Today's Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of dates in column J of my workbook which I would like to have a macro that will automatically filter to only show those rows with today's date in column J.

Also, it would be awesome if I can have the code to filter column J by the date referenced in cell K1.

Could anyone kindly help me out with the code for both?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code when I recorded my macro to manually select today's date in column J:

```
Sub Filter_Today()
'
' Filter_Today Macro
' Filter date column for today's date.
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$K$3416").AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "9/14/2018")
End Sub
```

Comment: You should try recording a macro and if it needs tweaking, come back, post the code and ask for help with that.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the code inside a code block. it is illegible in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter for today (dynamic) by using the special date filters.

```
Sub Filter_Today()

    with worksheets("sheet1")
        with .range(.cells(5, "J"), .cells(.rows.count, "J").end(xlup))
            .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=xlFilterToday, operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        end with
    end with

end sub
```

Filter on the value in K1 using a more conventional AutoFilter.

```
Sub Filter_K1()

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(5, "J"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Format(.Parent.Range("K1").Value, "=mm/dd/yy")
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The date formatting should match the date formatting used in column J.

Comment: I used your code and the filter is being applied to column A instead of J.

Comment: Did you keep `With .Range(.Cells(5, "J"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))` ?

Comment: Yes.  I copied and pasted your 1st code for today's date (dynamic).  The only edit I made was to change "sheet 1" for the actual sheet name.

Comment: That's odd; it doesn't perform that way for me. Must have something to do with worksheet formatting. The obvious solution would be to change to Field:=10. Also note my edit to the K1 problem.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped.  

For the today's date filter code, I changed to Field:=10 per your suggestion and it worked successfully.

For the K1 problem, I made the former edit (Field:=10) and also edited the date structure ("=mm/dd/yy") to the format that is defaulted on my excel sheet which was "=m/dd/yyyy" and it worked successfully.