# Sends all due dates in one email with copying due date rows data

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have code below whereby i fond it from the net and it is similar to what i would like to do. basically i have a due dates on column "J" and i want all due dates from 90 days ahead.

when it is found due dates which 90 days plus, it will copy each row which has due dates of 90 days plus on to temp sheet and continue to look for all due dates until there isn't any and then it will send email out and delete the temp sheet back to normal.

below code currently not working and i wonder if someone could help me.

```
Sub Send_Table_autofilter_2()

Dim MailBody As Range
Dim dwn As Range

'If filtered remove filter. Throws error if not filtered
  ActiveSheet.Range("j1").Activate
  On Error Resume Next
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Set mWs = Worksheets("Full")

'If MailBody sheet already exists then delete it
  If WorksheetExists("MailBody") Then
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("MailBody").Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

'Add a sheet to copy all todays date rows to
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "MailBody"
 

'Return to the mail content sheet
   mWs.Activate

'Set range as column A to check for todays date. If yes is found skip filter and mail creation
Set Rng = Range(Range("j1"), Range("j" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
          
    For Each cell In Rng
   If cell.Value <= Date + 90 Then

    If Not cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "yes" Then
   
   
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340156/excel-macro-to-filter-column-to-todays-date
  With Worksheets("Sheet5")
    With Rng
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterDate, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    End With
   End With
      
'Copy the autofilter range and header to the MailBody sheet
    Worksheets("Sheet5").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(0, 0).Copy Sheets("MailBody").Range("A1")
  
   
'Need to add yes to each autofiltered row and date. Column A is the range so offset by 10 and 11 columns.
    For Each dwn In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "yes"
    Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
    Next
   
   
   ActiveSheet.Range("j2").Activate
   ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
              

' Change the following as needed
    sSendTo = "JoeBloggs@yahoo.co.uk"
    sSendCC = ""
    sSendBCC = ""
    sSubject = "Due date reached"
      
MsgStr = sTemp = "Hello!" & "<br><br>"
         sTemp = sTemp & "The due date has been reached "
         sTemp = sTemp & "for this project:" & "<br><br>"
' Assumes project name is in column B
         sTemp = sTemp & " " & Cells(lRow, 2)
         sTemp = sTemp & "Please take the appropriate"
         sTemp = sTemp & "action." & "<br><br>"
         sTemp = sTemp & "Thank you!" & "<br>"


'Set Range on MailBody Sheet, then autofit it before copying to mail
  With Worksheets("MailBody")
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
 Set MailBody = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lRow, 7)) 'Columns 2 to 7
'Set MailBody = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, 10)) - Columns 1 to 10
  End With
 
  MailBody.Columns.AutoFit
   
                      
'Create mail
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
   
        With OutMail
            .To = sSendTo
            .CC = sSendCC
            .Subject = sSubject
            .HTMLBody = sTemp & RangetoHTML(MailBody)
            .Display
        'send
       End With
          
          
  End If
End If


MailTo = ""
MailSubject = ""
Next


'Delete MailBody sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Worksheets("MailBody").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range) ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
'Function from - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook


    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
   
    Rng.Copy
   
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial -4163, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial -4122, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With


    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=4, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=0)
        .Publish (True)
    End With


    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")


    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False


    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile


    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

'Does the worksheet exists
    Function WorksheetExists(WSName) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
```

Comment: How many emails should the script send ?

Comment: Hi as long as there isn't any Due date which will be 90 days + below it is the link of the sample book. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s4X64U84Zo_Zy3ScVKa1m4iwdK4nk-Zw/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a very large data set (and performance is an issue) then avoid the complexity of auto-filters by just scanning down the sheet and copying each row that satisfies the criteria.

Update 1 - ignore records with missing expiry dates

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Send_Table_autofilter_2()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsBody As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, dtDue As Date, iDays As Long
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iMailRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sDates As String, dtTimestamp As Date, sStatus As String
    Dim lines As New Collection

    ' delete existing MailBody Sheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
         If ws.Name = "MailBody" Then
             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
             ws.Delete
             Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         End If
    Next

    ' create new MailBody Sheet
    Set wsBody = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    wsBody.Name = "MailBody"

    ' header row
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Full")
    With wsBody.Range("A1:H1")
        .Value2 = ws.Range("C2:J2").Value2
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    iMailRow = 1

    ' scan sheet for due in <= 90 days
    ' copy to MailBody
    
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To iLastRow ' assume row2 is header
        If IsDate(ws.Cells(i, "J")) Then
            dtDue = ws.Cells(i, "J")
            iDays = DateDiff("d", Date, dtDue)
            sStatus = ws.Cells(i, "K")
            dtTimestamp = ws.Cells(i, "L")
            ws.Cells(i, "X") = iDays
    
            If iDays <= 90 And sStatus <> "Sent" Then
                iMailRow = iMailRow + 1
                ws.Range("C" & i & ":J" & i).Copy wsBody.Range("A" & iMailRow)
                lines.Add i, CStr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' check if any records in collection
    If lines.Count > 0 Then
        ' convert to html
        sDates = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy") & " and " & Format(Date + 90, "dd mmm yyyy")
        Call SendEmail(wsBody.UsedRange, sDates)
        
        ' record email sent
        For i = 1 To lines.Count
            ws.Range("K" & lines(i)) = "Sent"
            ws.Range("L" & lines(i)) = Now()
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No records due", vbInformation
    End If

    ' delete temp
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsBody.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub SendEmail(MailBody As Range, sDates As String)

   Const CSS = "<style>p{font:13px Verdana};</style>"
   
   Dim msg As String, outApp, outMail
   msg = "<p>Hello!" & "<br><br>" & _
    "The following are due between " & sDates & _
    "<br><br>Please take the appropriate action<br><br>Thank you!<br>"

    'Create mail
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
   
    With outMail
        .To = "JoeBloggs@yahoo.co.uk"
        .cc = "sSendCC"
        .Subject = "Due in next 90 days"
        .HTMLBody = CSS & msg & RangetoHTML(MailBody)
        .Display
        'send
    End With
    'outApp.Quit
    'Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range) As String
    
    Dim h As String, c As Integer, r As Long
    h = "<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""5"" border=""1"" style=""font:13px Verdana"">"

    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        h = h & "<tr>"
        For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If r = 1 Then ' header
               h = h & "<th bgcolor=""e0e0e0"">" & rng.Cells(1, c) & "</th>"
            Else
               h = h & "<td>" & rng.Cells(r, c) & "</td>"
            End If
        Next
        h = h & "</tr>"
    Next
    RangetoHTML = h & "</table>"

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Great Thank you so much for the code just got an 2 issues,  is it possiable to put email time stamp on the column "K and L" and it look for the time stamp from these column to avoid sending out an duplicate email with the same due dates and can we delete temp Mailbody afterwards the email has been sent

Comment: Hi it is great and it works  how i wanted too. only problem is that on my actual sheet has got some blanks cells in column "J" which are the expiry dates are still some missing therefore when i try  to run the code i get an error saying "Run Time Error 6, Over Flow" is there any away around this. Thank you so much for putting the codes together for me :)

Comment: @Harin Try changing `iDays As Integer` to `iDays As Long`

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply. i have tried changing to idays As Long and it works however it now copying including blanks rows which has got no dates in the cells.